# Use environment variables in YAML file

Tags: go, yaml, environment-variables

I have a GO script that generates pager duty on call reporting, and it has its own config.yaml file as such:

```
# PagerDuty auth token
pdAuthToken: 12345

# Explicitly set report time range (RFC822)
reportTimeRange:
  start: 01 Jan 20 00:00 UTC
  end: 01 Feb 20 00:00 UTC

# Rotation general information
rotationInfo:
  dailyRotationStartsAt: 8
  checkRotationChangeEvery: 30 # minutes
```

I need to pass environment variables in the config.yaml file. I tried to use `${THE_VARIABLE}` as such:

```
reportTimeRange:
    start: ${THE_VARIABLE}
```

Can anyone help on how I can passmy Linux environment variables in the config.yaml file without the need of editing the script.

Answer (score 1):

After unmarshaling the yaml file you can use `reflect` on the result to update any `string` fields whose value matches variable format of your choice.

```golang
var reVar = regexp.MustCompile(`^\${(\w+)}$`)

func fromenv(v interface{}) {
    _fromenv(reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem())// assumes pointer to struct
}

// recursive
func _fromenv(rv reflect.Value) {
    for i := 0; i < rv.NumField(); i++ {
        fv := rv.Field(i)
        if fv.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            fv = fv.Elem()
        }
        if fv.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            _fromenv(fv)
            continue
        }
        if fv.Kind() == reflect.String {
            match := reVar.FindStringSubmatch(fv.String())
            if len(match) > 1 {
                fv.SetString(os.Getenv(match[1]))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/1zuK7Mhtvsa

---

Alternatively, you could declare types that implement the `yaml.Unmarshaler` interface and use those types for fields in the config struct that expect the corresponding yaml properties to contain environment variables.

```golang
type Config struct {
    ReportTimeRange struct {
        Start StringFromEnv `yaml:"start"`
    } `yaml:"reportTimeRange"`
}

var reVar = regexp.MustCompile(`^\${(\w+)}$`)

type StringFromEnv string

func (e *StringFromEnv) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    var s string
    if err := value.Decode(&s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if match := reVar.FindStringSubmatch(s); len(match) > 0 {
        *e = StringFromEnv(os.Getenv(match[1]))
    } else {
        *e = StringFromEnv(s)
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Zy0rXJ7RRdC

Comment: Another option is to use yaml "tag" facility, though this requires the use of node parser (`Unmarshal` with destination type of `yaml.Node`). Faster and yields more stable results at the expense of more boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

Simples way is using `os.ExpandEnv`. Check `os.Expand` there https://go.dev/src/os/env.go to see how it works, while `os.ExpandEnv` is just wrapper for `Expand(s, Getenv)`.

This is how to use it: read file, replace placeholders and parse as `yaml`.

```
type Config struct {
    //some properties
}

func parseConfig(path string) (*Config, error) {
    data, err := os.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    replaced := os.ExpandEnv(string(data))
    cfg := &Config{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(replaced), cfg)
    return cfg, err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to replace the placeholder `{{ .THE_VARIABLE }}` with a environment var at program start in memory, without modifying the yaml file.

The idea is to load the yaml file into a var, use `template.Execute` to replace the data. Finally Unmarshal the string.

I just kept it simple.

YAML FILE:

`Start: {{ .THE_VARIABLE }}`

Replacing data:

```
fileData, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("test.yml")
var finalData bytes.Buffer
t := template.New("config")
t, err := t.Parse(string(fileData))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

data := struct {
    THE_VARIABLE int
}{
    THE_VARIABLE: 30,  // replace with os.Getenv("FOO")
}
t.Execute(&finalData, data)
str := finalData.String()
fmt.Println(str)
// unmarshal YAML here - from finalData.Bytes()
```

Output:
`Start: 30`